# Encrypt a Data in Jquery and Decrypt it in Server side code MVC C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

is there some encryption time that will encrypt a data and possible to Decrypt it in C# code??
could you give me some ideas i just need to encrypt a data and decrypt it in the server side codes having trouble finding one.

Comment: use your own algoritm like add 10 to each char

Comment: https://github.com/gabrieleromanato/jQuery-MD5
have a look at this link

Comment: i thing md5 cannot be decrypted once you encrypt a string. is there some plug in available?

Comment: Can't you use an https connection? That way no data encryption is needed in javascript. If not, then take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457234/encrypt-in-javascript-decrypt-in-php-using-public-key-cryptography) question.

Comment: I use https but when im looking in the developer's tool in google chrome the value of the ajax call still visible its not encrypted i wanted to encrypt that..

Answer (score 0):

Nothing you do in javascript is going to be able to prevent someone from using the developers tool to see the unencrypted values. At best you will prevent novices from peeking, but it will be trivially easy to see what the JS code is doing for any developer/techie, and thus see the value you are trying to protect.

If you are trying to protect data during transmission, use SSL, if you are trying to encrypt something on the client side, in JS, to prevent people from using the developers tools to see the value in google chrome, good luck.